# Wordpress token in pages

Tags: php, wordpress, broadcast

We currently have a multi site wordpress set up, and use broadcast so that we can create 1 page on 1 site, and then push this page to all other sites within the multisite network. This is working perfectly, however, requires that the shared pages are generic (ie contain no reference to the sub site that it sits on). tried to look for a plugin, or how to change this with no such luck.

We would like to place tokens into the page content ie Welcome to [$Site_Name] where $Site_Name would be a configured name on child site. 
This way, when broadcasting the page, they would appear to be unique.  Is this currently possible some how?

Comment: Hi Simon, I think short-code will work fine here, like [child-site-name] , now this shortcode will be function which calls get_current_blog_id or something which helps you retieve all info and then return sitename accrodingly.. (being short-code and part of theme/plugin it will be child-site specific)

Answer (score 1):

In such cases, [short-code](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode) in the content works fine.

We can use any php or wp function and it will be executed in the context of the child site.

For child site name we have this function called: `get_bloginfo()` with default "" (empty) arguments, it returns site name.

So in our case we can use something like this:

```
add_shortcode( 'child-sitename', 'wm_child_sitename' );
function wm_child_sitename(){
 return get_bloginfo();
}
```

Now in the site content we can use [child-sitename] short-code.

For more info about WP functions used:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_bloginfo/
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode